# Spring batch continue job when a step fails

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need the job to continue when one of the steps fails. Steps are dynamically generated and are independent.

```
  public Step step(Long id) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("STEP_" + id)
        .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
          service.action(id);
          return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }).build();
  }
```

I want to save the FAILED state if it fails but not terminate the execution. Is there a way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You did not share your job flow definition, but it seems like it is a sequential flow, in which the default is to fail the job at the first step that fails, see [Sequential Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#SequentialFlow).

You need to define a conditional flow, as documented in [Conditional Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow). Here is a quick example:

```
@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(stepA())
                .on("*").to(stepB())
                .from(stepA()).on("FAILED").to(stepC())
                .end()
                .build();
}
```

Comment: Good approach, I think it will be able to continue his workflow with that kind of implementation.

Comment: It's a good way but it doesn't work for my implementation. I made a small "cheat" so that the process would not end if there was an error in any of the steps. In the afterStep (StepExecutionListener) frame on error the status to COMPLETED and the ExitStatus FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job flow. It is generated dynamically. There will always be a first step (remove(0)). This works for me. I would only need to implement the jump of the error with the failed step

```
SimpleJobBuilder jobBuilder = this.jobBuilderFactory.get("JOB").start(steps.remove(0));
      for(Step step : steps) {
        jobBuilder.next(step);
      }
return jobBuilder.build();
```